# Problems with the type of cloud DB HMS

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, appgallery-connect, clouddb, agconnect-functions

I have a problem with the Cloud DB

```
Message:{"defaultName":"AGCError","name":"database-server","errorCode":{"code":"2052","message":"the input object is invalid."}}
```

I don't know what could be the reason ?

Comment: Can I learn that which SDK you used? From which interface you got this error? What is your input parameter value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the Huawei Documentation, The error code 2052, it is described as “invalid input object”. So please check your input value or object

**Below might be the causes. Please check:**

1. Check any field longer input values which you declared as string. Because **string data type field maximum value range is 200 character only**. If the string contains more than 200 characters, you are advised to use the Text type. Refer -
   https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-clouddb-data-type-0000001080815898#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001176121166__en-us_topic_0000001127251477_table2376546172218
2. Check the date field format. Because the **date format should be (yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss sss)** like below